# how to take addition in json data

Tags: jquery, html, json

I need Addition of `qty` in `+ (sum of qty) +`. What do I need to do?

```
[{"qty": "34"},{"qty": "5"}]
```

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "localhost/sp/text.json", //json link
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            items.push("<tr>");
            items.push("<td id=''" + key + "''>" + val.qty + < /td>");
            items.push("<td id=''" + key + "''>" + (sum of qty) + < /td>"); //need sum of qty here
            items.push("</tr>");
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate sum using other loop like :

```
$.ajax({
url: "localhost/sp/text.json", //json link
dataType:'json',
success: function(data){
var items = [];

//count sum
var sumqty=0;
$.each(data,function(key,val){  
sumqty=sumqty+parseInt(val.qty);
});
//

$.each(data,function(key,val){  
items.push("<tr>");
items.push("<td id='" +key+ "'>" + val.qty+</td>");
items.push("<td id='" +key+ "'>" + sumqty +</td>"); //need sum of qty here
items.push("</tr>");
});}});
```

Comment: sir its gives result as 0345

Comment: please replace line with `sumqty=sumqty+parseInt(val.qty);` use parseInt()

Comment: if i have [{status="IN"},{status: "out"},{status:"IN"}] then how to get IN Count

Comment: similar way just add there condition to comare value like `var sumqty=0;
$.each(data,function(key,val){  
 if(val.status=="IN"){ sumqty++; }
});
alert(sumqty);`

Answer (score 0):

The "sum of qty" will have the same value in each node?

If so...

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'localhost/sp/text.json', //json link
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var items = [],
            sum = 0;
        $.each(data, function(k, obj) {
            sum += parseInt(obj.qty, 10);
        });
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            items.push('<tr>');
            items.push('<td id="' + key + '">' + val.qty + '</td>');
            items.push('<td id="' + key + '">' + sum + '</td>');
            items.push('</tr>');
        });
    }
});
```

Was missing a few quotes.

**Edit**
Not NaN anymore.

Comment: sorry its gives result NaN

Comment: The way Bharat Bhatiya said is great.